# Proof for a seemingly simple property for fully-connected coloured random graphs?

Tags: marginal-distribution, graph-theory, exchangeability

I have a probability distribution defined over a set of fully-connected simple graphs depending on their coloring. Let us have a fully connected graph with $N$ nodes, a node may have a color $i$ amongst $M$ possible colors with a probability $p_i$. Given a pair of nodes $(c,d)$ such that $c$ has color  $i$ and $d$ has a color $j$, the edge between $c$ and $d$ has a color $l$ amongst $Q$ possible colours with probability $p_{ijl}$. Hence, the probability of a graph with $k_i$ nodes of color $i$ and $h^{ij}_l$ edges of color $l$ is given as:

$$\prod_{i}(p_i)^{k_i}\prod_{i\leq j}\prod_{l}(p^{ij}_{l})^{h^{ij}_l}$$

Obviously, $\sum_i k_i = N$ and $\sum_l h^{ij}_l = k_i\times k_j$ if $i \neq j$ and $\sum_l h^{ij}_l = {k_i\choose 2}$ if $i = j$

Now, how can I prove that the probability distribution over graphs with $N$ nodes obtained by marginalising out probability distribution over $N+K$ nodes is same as the original probability distribution over the graphs with $N$ nodes ?

Comment: Would "fully-connected" mean *complete,* or just *connected,* or something else?

Comment: Fully connected means Complete